# GraphQL: generate long query while I select only one column (product name)

Tags: postgresql, graphql, apollo, nestjs, typegraphql

I use postgres & GraphQL & NestJS with TypeScript And typeORM

My GraphQL query is:

```
{
   Product { 
    name 
   }
}
```

But in the query logs I see the generated query is:

```
SELECT 
 "ProductEntity"."id" AS "ProductEntity_id",
 "ProductEntity"."name" AS "ProductEntity_name",
 "ProductEntity"."description" AS "ProductEntity_description",
 "ProductEntity"."price" AS "ProductEntity_price" 
FROM "product" "ProductEntity"
```

so why not just like the following ?

```
SELECT 
     "ProductEntity"."name" AS "ProductEntity_name",
FROM "product" "ProductEntity"
```

Kindly find the Product Resolver below:

```
@Resolver('product')
export class ProductResolver {
  constructor(private readonly productService: ProductService) {}

  @Query()
  async product() {
    return this.productService.getProducts();
  }

}
```

Product Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(ProductEntity)
    private readonly productRepository: Repository<ProductEntity>,
  ) {}


  async getProducts() {
    return await this.productRepository.find();
  }

}
```

Comment: This question would be specific to whatever ORM you're using and how you're using that ORM inside your resolver class. Most ORMs, like TypeORM and Sequelize, select all available fields by default unless you explicitly tell them which fields to select.

Comment: @DanielRearden 

here is my Resolver 

@Resolver('product')
export class ProductResolver {
  constructor(private readonly productService: ProductService) {}

  @Query(() => [FindProductDto])
  async product() {
    return this.productService.getProducts();
  }
}

as I understand from your comment, should I create query function in my resolver for each query that I need to trigger ?

Comment: Please edit your question with the code -- putting code blocks in comments make the code very hard to read. That aside, we have no idea what `getProducts` is or does. If that's Sequelize, then you would have to provide it the `attributes` option to specify which columns to select.

Comment: @DanielRearden please check the updated post

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Rearden said, this is more an issue with the ORM you are using. Most ORMs grab as much information as possible unless you tell them to otherwise. Furthermore, you ORM has no idea about what information the GraphQL request is asking, so it can't determine what fields to pull. Rather, the ORM pulls all the fields possible and maps them to an object, then passes it to the GraphQL resolver, where GraphQL strips the unnecessary and sends the response back to the client. This way, whether you asked for 5 or 50 fields, all of them are available to the GrpahQL resolver. You could probably get clever about reading what fields are asked for and then make your ORM return only those fields, but that will require significant testing and a decently good understanding of how the GQL context works.